# Restoring a hard drive permissions after reinstalling

Tags: windows, permissions

After reinstalling Windows, the advanced security settings for other hard drives in the system have retained previous installation settings, e.g. the owner is an unknown SID and so on.

I would like to restore these permissions to match the actual installation.

After some search, it appears that the following command *may be* appropriate:

```
icacls "full path to the folder" /reset /t /c /l
```

**Question:**

Is this the right way for restoring default permissions on a hard drive?

Comment: The command won't harm anything but you need to instead take ownership of the files.  This requires you to be an Administrator on the system.

Comment: Alright, who shall I set the owner as ? Me, SYSTEM, TrustedInstaller like in C: etc.

Comment: I assume your talking about a system disk from another machine? If that is the case simply taking ownership of an Administrator that currently exists should be enough.  You can also assign the owner to the machine's Administrators user group.

Comment: No, it isn't the system hard drive, it's another drive with documents, etc.

Comment: External dives by default should allow read & write permissions from everyone.  The only way this is NOT the case, is if the drive is a system drive (i.e. Windows was installed to it) or the permissions were modified manually. Is the existence of an unknown user SID a simply annoyance or is it preventing you from altering files contained on the drive.

Comment: The drive isn't external but internal. Anyway, making some progress, it appears that after creating a partition from disk manager, the owner is SYSTEM, but then formatting the drive from Explorer it changes to Administrators. Now reassigning the owner, that's going to be pretty long, coming back when it's done!

Comment: External in this context is any disk other than the system partition. If you have already formatted the drive the current installation should have full access to the drive without any additional steps being required unless you manually changed the permissions on the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after seriously looking at it I've posted a community answer as there really isn't a clear answer on the web about it, feel free to edit it if you spot anything wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

After thoroughly looking at the problem, here's my own answer to the question of *whether non-system, non-external drives permissions should be reset to match the newly installed operating system* (same version).

This is what an internal drive's security permissions are after:

- deleting the partitions
- creating one partition and format it in Explorer

**Owner:**

*Administrators*

**Permissions:**

| Principal | Access |
| --- | --- |
| Adminsitrators (*Computer name*\Administrators) | Full control |
| Authenticated Users | Modify |
| SYSTEM | Full control |
| Users (*Computer name*\Users) | Read & execute |

**Permissions properties (all of them):**

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Type | Allow |
| Inherited from | None |
| Applies to | This folder, subfolders and files |

Basically, if the permissions do match, there's **absolutely** nothing to do because these are [well-known SIDs](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Well-known%20Security%20Identifiers), i.e. they point exactly to the same principal even though the computer operating system has been reinstalled.

But as **@Ramhound** pointed out, you may eventually have to take ownership for the drive:

[image]